# Create A Function To Find Elements Of Same Length In Tuple/List

Tags: python, string, list, function, tuples

I'm trying to create a function that takes a integer as a parameter and uses it to display elements in the tuple/list with the same length

```
names=('Delta', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Charlie', 'Beta')
num_letter = Input('enter number')


def number_letters_same_length(int(num_letter))
if len(names) == int(num_letter):
    print(names)
else:
print('no names with same length found')
```

The goal is to display list of all names with same number entered in parameter, if not it should display a error message saying 'No names found with same length'

Comment: You need to loop over the names list and compare each name len to the required len

Comment: Input is not a builtin function

Answer (score 3):

what about this

```
name_list = [name for name in names if len(name) == num_letter]
if name_list:
   print(name_list)
else:
   print('no names with same length found')
```